# How do I search my git aliases?

Tags: git

There are some aliases that I use less frequently and want to check before I execute.

How can I easily search my `git` aliases?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/337/aliases/1189/list-search-existing-aliases#t=201609131954278856447

Answer (score 5):

Add to your `.gitconfig` under `[alias]`:

```
aliases = !git config --list | grep ^alias\\. | cut -c 7- | grep -Ei --color \"$1\" "#"
```

Then you can do

- `git aliases commit` - show aliases containing "commit"
- `git aliases ^st=` - show what the `st` alias does
- `git aliases` - show ALL aliases

The first argument is an (optional) POSIX extended regular expression. Any additional arguments are ignored.

Comment: This will also grep the full command, not just the alias name. So, `git alias c` would return any command that contained the letter `c` instead of just alias names that contain the letter `c`

Comment: That's actually intentional. I sometimes forget what my alias name is (I have lots containing "commit", as per the example). I've added an instruction on grepping only the alias name itself.

Answer (score 0):

`git --list-cmds=alias` lists all aliases.[1] So you can for example pipe that to `grep`:

```
git --list-cmds=alias | grep log
```

#### Notes

1. `man git` as of `git version 2.40.0`: “This is an internal/experimental option and may change or be removed in the future.”